# Add ViewModel to Mobile View

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on making a separate set of views for mobile devices, rather than using additional adaptive UI states for the phone. I am able to achieve this by adding a sub-folder in my `Views` folder called `DeviceFamily-Mobile` and adding a new `View` with the same name as the one I am overriding.

I have the following `View` that will work and display "MOBILE" on a mobile device/emulator.

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.PayeesPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
      xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
      xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:models="using:MyApp.Models"
      xmlns:viewModels="using:MyApp.ViewModels"
      xmlns:views="using:MyApp.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="MobileTextBlock"
                   Foreground="{ThemeResource ForegroundColorBrush}"
                   Text="MOBILE" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

However, if I try to set the `DataContext` to allow me to actual display something useful, like so:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:PayeesPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Then I get an error when navigating to the `PayeesPage`:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' to type 'MyApp.ViewModels.PayeesPageViewModel'.

This is the same way I set the `DataContext` on the original `PayeesPage` and it works fine. Is there a different way to set the `DataContext` on these alternate `View`s, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the mobile `View` needs to have the same `x:Class` as the original `Page`. ReSharper was complaining when I tried to call it `MyApp.Views.PayeesPage` because that already existed, so I changed it to `MyApp.PayeesPage`. However, when I switched it back so that both were using the same `x:Class` then everything started working as expected.

Unfortunately, I am getting a bunch of red squigglies from ReSharper, but things are working as they should be. Just in case anyone comes across this question in the future:

**Views/PayeesPage.xaml:**

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.Views.PayeesPage"
 ...>
```

**Views/DeviceFamily-Mobile/PayeesPage.xaml:**

```
<Page x:Class="MyApp.Views.PayeesPage"
 ...>
```

Comment: thx for sharing your solution, there are lots of articles talk about DeviceFamily-Type folder, for example http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/

Comment: That is a nice article - where I got a lot of my information. My issue was that none of the information that I found pointed out that the views needed to share the same `x:Class`, so the red squigglies from ReSharper were a bit misleading in this case.